# Can SQL*Plus read environment variables from the machine is it running on?

Tags: oracle, environment-variables, sqlplus

I'm aware that the database engine itself is (often) on another machine and that SQL*Plus has no direct way of reading *those* environment variables, but I'm in a tricky situation where I merely need the environment variables from the machine the client itself is running on.

Is there a way to cheat these values into the SQL*Plus client from within a single script that will be run in SQL*Plus? The script consists of a single begin/end PL/SQL block, but if I need to use SQL*Plus directives of the set/define/variable sort that shouldn't be a problem either.

What I can't do is alter the way that the SQL*Plus executable itself is started (I don't have access to pass the values in as arguments).

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Note: `dbms_system.get_env()` seems to retrieve environment variables from the server itself, which is what I do not want.

Comment: Which environment variables? If they're related to Oracle you might be able to get them from you session.

Comment: Custom environment variables. Not Oracle related.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get a few client-related things from [the `USERENV` context](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions184.htm#g1513460), but not arbitrary environment variables.

If you can create a file on your local machine you could use [the `host` command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve026.htm) to set a substitution variable based on an environment variable:

```
SQL > host echo define homedir=$HOME > /tmp/gethome.sql

SQL > @/tmp/gethome.sql
SQL > host rm -f /tmp/gethome.sql

SQL > select '&homedir.' as home from dual;

HOME
------------
/home/apoole

1 row selected.
```

Not very pretty, but if you can't pass the variables on the command line as positional parameters then your options are rather limited.

This is using a Unix-y paths and commands of course, but you can do the same sort of thing in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you could pass the variable via [sqlplus argument passing mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#i1169914). you could do the following,

```
cat > myscript.sql <<!
select '&1' as HOME from DUAL;
!

sqlplus user/pwd@db @myscript.sql $HOME
```

Answer (score 0):

`Sys_context` should solve your problem. You can set custom environment variable in database using `DBMS_SESSION.SET_CONTEXT ('MY_NAMESPACE', 'MY_PARAMETER', v_input_parameter);` and then fetch it using `SYS_CONTEXT ('MY_NAMESPACE', 'MY_PARAMETER');`
So you can run a initial pl/sql block to set variable in session and then use it as per requirement.

You can see an example here: http://blog.contractoracle.com/2010/03/using-dbmssessionsetcontext-to-store.html

Comment: How do you get the OS environment variable into the context though?

Comment: OP is willing to set the variables via script, so that will be a manual step.

Comment: "I don't have access to pass the values in as arguments" - so they aren't available as positional parameters. Maybe we're talking about different things.

Comment: @AlexPoole OP says he can't pass arguments while launching SQL plus client. A script may be python can pick env. variable and set it in DB.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using an empty sql script.

The script 'getvar.sql' just needs to be an empty file.

When sqlplus is called with 'getvar.sql', everything in the command line after that is stored to named substitution variables; &1, &2, etc

```
$  touch getvar.sql

$  sql /nolog @getval "Fred"

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.2.0 Production on Mon Mar 13 13:10:33 2023

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SP2-0640: Not connected
@ > prompt &1
Fred
```