# Unable to MKDIR using %userprofile% from within SQL*plus

Tags: windows, batch-file, sqlplus

On Windows I'm spooling the results of a PL/SQL loop to a .csv file from within SQL*Plus, executed from a batch file. Prior to spooling the .csv file, I want to create a windows directory to contain the file in a user's documents folder using `%USERPROFILE%\documents` variable.

Running the MKDIR in isolation from command line like so:

```
MKDIR -p "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\my-dir\my-sub-dir"
```

Creates the folder I would like i.e. `C:\Users\christofflam\Documents\my-dir\my-sub-dir`, but calling that code from within SQL*Plus creates a literal parent directory called `%USERPROFILE%` in whichever directory `cmd.exe` is running from.

The following code is being called from within the SQL*Plus command file:

```
HOST MKDIR -p "%USERPROFILE%\Documents\my-dir\my-sub-dir"
```

Which results in the creation of literal directory `C:\my-cmdexe-dir\%USERPROFILE%\Documents\my-dir\my-sub-dir`

How do I create the desired directory in `%USERPROFILE%` from within SQL*Plus command file?

Comment: @GerhardBarnard `tempfile.txt` shows `dom1\christofflam` where `dom1` is my corporate network

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can SQL\*Plus read environment variables from the machine is it running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30107510/can-sqlplus-read-environment-variables-from-the-machine-is-it-running-on)